# JQUERY $(function() { initialisation

Tags: jquery

I've been working with JQuery for some time now and I've always used the following to initalise my javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
// Initalisation logic
});
```

However, recently I've noticed a lot of examples using the following:

```
$(function() {

});
```

Whats the difference?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for the awesome fast feedback!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, there isn't one. The `$(...)` format is a shortcut. See [the API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) for `jQuery()` for details.

I like to use it like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // ...all of my jQuery-specific code here...
});
```

...because then if I need to, I can use [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) if I end up having to mix something into the page that also wants the `$` symbol, but I can still use `$` in my code (because jQuery passes itself into the callback as the first argument, and as you can see I'm accepting that argument as `$` in my callback function — and so that shadows any global `$` symbol that another library might be using). The above also has the advantage that I can have symbols global to *my* code (`var`s within the anonymous function) that are not actually globals.

Comment: How often do you mix something into the page that wants the $ symbol? I am just curious since it does not happen often where I work.

Comment: @finneycanhelp: Not often, I try to avoid mixing together too many libraries. But for instance, if slowly migrating a site from jQuery to Prototype (or MooTools) or from those to jQuery, `noConflict` is important, because Prototype and MooTools also use and rely on the `$` symbol.

Comment: were these always equivalent? or did '$(function() {' start acting like '$(document).ready(' in newer versions of jquery?

Comment: @house9: It's been true since jQuery 1.0 (August 2006). I don't know about the various alpha and beta releases before that.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is a matter of style.  One is just a shortcut of the other. :)
See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ near the bottom where it says "Executes the function when the DOM is ready to be used"

When I asked one of the jQuery UI people what they preferred, he said he preferred the more verbose way. However, people in my shop use this version:

```
$(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the first is more readable. So please just use this one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Initalisation logic
});
```

Comment: Agree that `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` is more readable than `$(function() { ... })`, but I think `jQuery(function($) { ... });` is perfectly readable. Like any idiom, you have to learn it once.

Comment: I do not, you are passing a function to jQuery, but there is no hint whatsoever what jQuery is going to do with that function.

Comment: Like I said, like any idiom, you have to learn it once. Now, if you (like me) think that the `jQuery` function has **way** too many *completely different* things that it does depending on what you pass in (even doing different things when you pass in strings, depending on the content of the string), no argument there, it's one of my pet peeves about jQuery. But at least it only has the *one* thing it does when you pass in a function by itself.

Comment: It's more descriptive, but that doesn't automatically make it more readable. Personally I find the other being more readable because it's shorter.

Comment: as TJ mentioned, it's something that you learn once and just remember. Of course cryptic names should be avoided, but `document ready` is used so often that a shortcut like that is not confusing at all. You could say the `$` symbol is bad too, since it's not as explicit as `jQuery`, but again, it's about how commonly it is used, and hence how easy it is to remember.